# Load layout once in Fat-Free Framework

Tags: php, html, fat-free-framework

I think this should have a pretty simple explanation but I'm still learning Fat-Free Framework (F3):  How do I render only once the header and footer and switch out the content code for the selected route?  I have this code:

```
$f3->route('GET /',
  function($f3) {
    $f3->set('content','views/welcome.htm');
    $f3->set('page_head', 'Welcome');
  }
);
```

And if I add this line:

```
echo View::instance()->render('layouts/header+footer.htm');
```

either after the `f3->set` calls in the route or after `$f3->run();` at the end of the index.php file, the whole page refreshes on a route change.  I can't call that `echo` line above before the route code without throwing an error in the content box.

Is there any way to disable the page refreshing?  Is it being refreshed because my links are being interpreted as separate pages by the browser?  Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a little hazy. But I will try to answer in the way I understand.
First your `index.php`

```
$f3->route('GET /',
  function($f3) {
    $f3->set('content','views/welcome.htm');
    $f3->set('page_head', 'Welcome');
    echo Template::instance()->render('layouts/header+footer.htm');
  }
);
$f3->run();
```

In your `header+footer.htm`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{{@page_head}}</title>
</head>
<body>
<include href="{{@content}}"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Your `views/welcome.htm` can contain anything.

```
<h1>Welcome</h1>
<p>You have arrived to the welcome page</p>
```

Please remember the folders `views` and `layouts` should be in the `UI` folder

```
$f3->set('UI','ui/');
```

On your comment:
You can access the params of a request from `$f3->get('PARAMS')` or you can do this.

```
$f3->route('GET /@page',
      function($f3,$params) {
        $page = $params['page'];
        $f3->set('content','views/'. $page .'.htm');
        $f3->set('page_head', 'Welcome');
        echo Template::instance()->render('layouts/header+footer.htm');
      }
    );
```

This should work

Comment: So I used to have that.  The problem is, imagine I have 4 other routes and they are linked in the navigation, any time I click on a different route, say one with the URL "/information", the entire page refreshes, including the navigation.  Can the navigation be loaded only once while the `f3->set('content', 'views/information.htm')` is switched out?  Can the navigation be persistent across routes?

Comment: Does my improved answer sort this? 
if you want a single page app you might have to user a javascript framework like AngularJs: An example here https://scotch.io/tutorials/single-page-apps-with-angularjs-routing-and-templating

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to update only a portion of a web page, without doing a full refresh, then you need to use AJAX.

Start by reading this:
https://fatfreeframework.com/3.6/routing-engine#AJAXandSynchronousRequests

You'll need to use javascript on the front end to make this work. If you don't know how to code this in javascript, then you can start by reading this:

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp

You may find it easier to use Jquery, which is a very popular javascript library. You can read about it here:

https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_ajax.asp

Answer (score 0):

Maybe will be not bad to create your own instance of View and extend the main with functionality similar to PHPTal Filters. Then you can set Header in preFilter and Footer in postFilter and extend render() function. The extended render() will render everything together for you including header, footer and body content.

I don't have personally anything against FatFree View but will suggest PHPTal as a templating engine - here simply implementation https://github.com/creoLIFE/FatFree-PHPTAL including Header/Footer served from separate files.